# variable isn't array error for static array itcl

Tags: tcl, itcl

I have a static variable in my itcl class

```
public common x  {};
```

Whenever I am trying to access the variable using `info exists x ($key)`, I get an error variable isn't array.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not familiar with itcl, but supposing normal Tcl rules still apply, once you've assigned a value to a variable, you can't access it using array syntax. If `x` is an array variable, you can use the syntax `x($key)` to check for existence, assign values, or retrieve values. But if you have assigned a value like `{}` to `x`, it can't be used as an array variable.

Comment: What about some [MCVE]?

Comment: @PeterLewerin , You are right the initialization of the variable was wrong .

Comment: @purplepsycho , Will take care of this next time Thanks